# How variables are sent to the functions in scheme?

Tags: function, variables, scheme

I'm new to scheme. When I run the following code

```
(define lst '(1))

(let ((func1 (lambda lst 
               (begin (display lst)
                      lst))))
  (begin (display lst) 
         (func1 lst)))
```

I got `(1)((1))'((1))`, which means lst displays as `(1)` when called in the fourth line, but when send it to the function `func1`, it becomes `((1))`. What exactly happened here?

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail: you mean [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)? Hadn't seen that yet, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(lambda Args E)` means: bind the variable-length argument list of this function to `Args`. E.g.

```
(define f (lambda args `(got ,(length args) arguments)))
(display (f 'foo 'bar 'baz))
```

will print `(got 3 arguments)`. If you change the `lambda` expression to

```
(lambda (lst) (begin (display lst) lst))
;;;     ^---^
```

then the function will print, and return, its single argument.

Answer (score 2):

In a `lambda` form, when you write this:

```
(lambda x <body>)
```

... you're declaring that `x` is a *list* of parameters with zero or more elements. On the other hand, this:

```
(lambda (x) <body>)
```

... is stating that `x` is a single parameter. In the question, this code (the `begin` is unnecessary for the body part in a `lambda`):

```
((lambda lst (display lst) lst) '(1))
```

... will display and return the list of parameters; if we pass `'(1)` it will evaluate to `'((1))`: a list with a single element which happens to be a list.

Surely you intended to do this instead:

```
((lambda (lst) (display lst) lst) '(1))
```

... which will display and return the single parameter it receives - in case of passing `'(1)` the above expression will evaluate to `'(1)`, the parameter itself.